# setting NaNs to zero in an anonymous function inline

Tags: matlab, vectorization, anonymous-function

I implemented a piecewise function using an anonymous function that can also be evaluated in vectors or matrices:

```
 f = @(x) exp(((x-.25).*(x-.75)).^-1) .* (.25 < x & x < .75);
```

The problem is when evaluating it at exactly `0.25` or `0.75` we try to evaluate `Inf * 0` which results in `NaN`. I would like to set these `NaN` values to zero. I am aware that this can easily be done using a function defined in a file, but I'm wondering whether there is a solution that would let you do this inline. (Possible defining other anonymous helper functions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of the `NaN`'s, you can exploit the fact that some functions like [`max`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) ignore `NaN`'s:

```
>> max(NaN, 0)
ans =
     0
```

which also works vectorized:

```
>> max([1 2 NaN 4], 0)
ans =
     1     2     0     4
```

---

The mathematical function you are working with is non-negative. So if `y` is an array resulting from the anonymous function as defined in your question, `max(y, NaN)` will leave numeric entries of `y` untouched, and will transform `NaN` into `0`.

In conclusion, modify the anonymous function to **include an outer `max(..., 0)`**:

```
f = @(x) max(exp(((x-.25).*(x-.75)).^-1) .* (.25 < x & x < .75), 0);
```

This gives, for example,

```
>> f([.2 .25 .4 .5 .6 .75 .8])
ans =
   1.0e-06 *
         0         0    0.0053    0.1125    0.0053         0         0
```

Comment: That is *a lot* shorter and therefore more elegant, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
g = @(x) sum(cat(length(size(x))+1,x-1,~isnan(x)),length(size(x))+1,'omitnan');
x=1./(rand(100)>0.5);x=x.*0;x=x+10; %demo data with nan and 10
y=g(x); %now it has 0 and 10;
```

The trick is using sum with 'omitnan'. It sums 1 to every non-nan value and 0 to every nan. It omits nan in the summation, so every nan becomes 0. By substracting 1 from every value beforehand it returns the original value.

ofcourse

```
x(isnan(x))=0;
```

also works, but not in an an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `'omitnan'`! - It is however still not a very elegant solution:)

Comment: The elegant solution would be to just use "isnan" as index and set those values to 0. (last code line in the answer)

Comment: Well that last line is elegant indeed, but not an answer.

Comment: :D let's see if someone comes up with a better answer

Comment: Let's see! Just to be clear I do appreciate your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So assumig `x` is a column vector following solution would work, but is not very elegant:

```
deNaNify1 = @(x)x((2:2:end)-isnan(x(2,:)));
deNaNify = @(x)deNaNify1([zeros(size(x'));x'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: For real numbers following sets NaNs to zero:

```
denanify = @(y) min(y,0)-min(-y,0)
```